# Frameset Showing in Homepage source

Tags: web-deployment, frameset

When I view my website's homepage view-source i only see this code.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>pingbuddy.com</title>
</head>
<frameset rows="100%,*" border="0">
  <frame src="http://54.210.173.108" frameborder="0" />
  <frame frameborder="0" noresize />
</frameset>
<!-- pageok -->
<!-- 09 -->
<!-- -->
</html>
```

I Don't Know From Where This Frameset Came. Open Pingbuddy(Dot)Com and Please Help Me To Solve This issue.

Comment: Help you with what? What is the problem? the frameset is part of the html.

Comment: no this is not part of my website.. my actual webpage is this : http://54.210.173.108

Comment: i donno how this come to my homepage..

Comment: you are loading website in frameset, so it is coming in frame

Comment: Welcome. How is this related to `Java` or `Javascript`?

Comment: You seem to have bought a cheap domain name somewhere, that only uses a frameset to embed your page from a different address. Check with your domain hoster, if they offer an option to actually point the domain to your server’s IP via the DNS. If they don’t, then you need to transfer the domain to a different hoster, that does offer this.

Answer (score 0):

When loading one html document in another html document it's done inside [frame](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frame.asp) or [iframe](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) tag. Since you are loading your site (`54.210.173.108`) in another site (`Pingbuddy.Com`) you need to use `<frame>` or `<iframe>`.

Using `<frame>` requires `<frameset>` to hold it (and it also not supported in HTML5). Use `<iframe>` instead.